# Multiple Joins to get data and counts from multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, left-join

This is probably really simple, but I have been struggling. Basically I need to combine 2 different queries:

1. Get a list of accounts plus some info for each
2. Based on each of those accounts, get the count of users and forms associated with each.

So given the following table structure:

[image]

I want to get back:

```
Name      Users    Forms     Active
====================================
Child 1     3        4          T
Child 2     4        3          F
```

So the problem is that I want to query first based on the Master id:

```
Select * from ACCOUNT where MasterId = 1026

AccntId   Name  Master Id   Active
====================================
2       Child 1    1026        T         
3       Child 2    1026        F
```

Then for each of those returned I would like to get the counts of users and forms.

```
Select Count(AccntId) as Users from Form Where AccntId=2
```

And of course all in one query. I have messed around with Joins and Left Joins and the stumbling block in the initial query.

Comment: One approach is create a SubQuery for FormCount and UserCount showing Count and group. Look for Group By in SQL help. Then join Account table with FormCount and UserCount.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the final query for anyone who cares turned out to be:

```
SELECT
    A.Id as AccountId, A.Name, A.Active, 
   (select count(*) as Users FROM UserProfile UP where A.Id = UP.AccountId), 
   (select count(*) as Forms FROM Form F where A.Id = F.AccountId)
FROM
    Account A
WHERE
    A.MasterId = 1026 
Group By A.Id, A.Name, A.Active
```

Which gave me ultimately the numbers I was looking for:

```
AccountId   Name    Active  Users   Forms
1           Child     T      3       4
5          Child2     F      4       3
```

Not sure if that is the most efficient or proper approach, but it does work! Thanks for the hints from the commentators

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT acc.MasterId, count(up.AccntId) as Users, count(f.AccntId) as Forms
from Account acc
full join UserProfile up
    on up.AccntId = acc.AccntId
full join Form f
    on f.AccntId = acc.AccntId
-- Where /* Your conditions */
group by acc.MasterId;
```

This should work.

Edit: joins changed to left join

Comment: Tried the above without success. Group By acc.MasterId resulted in only 1 row (needed 2). Changed to acc.AccntId got the two rows I was looking for but counts were way over inflated. Any thoughts?

Comment: SELECT acc.Id, count(up.AccountId) as Users, count(f.AccountId) as Forms
from Account acc
join UserProfile up
    on up.AccountId = acc.Id
join Form f
    on f.AccountId = acc.Id
WHERE acc.MasterId = 1026
group by acc.Id;